# Writing data using libxl library

Tags: c++, libxl

I am calling the xlCreateBook() function. Before that my program holds more memory because i am reading a huge file. After called the xlCreateBook() it returns the null pointr to the Sheet variable.

But once i loaded the less size file it xlCreateBook() functions working correctly. Help me to get out of this.

Comment: How do you want us to help you if you don't put your code ? Please read [Stack Overflow's Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)   and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Which method returns a null pointer? `AddSheet()`? It's strange that it would be related to size to write, since at the sheet creation, you have not added data yet. What does `Book::errorMessage()` say when you get a null sheet pointer?

Maybe what you are trying to save is too big for the old xls format, and you should create an xlsx file, by using `xlCreateXMLBook()` instead?

If you really are lacking memory because of something else, there is not much that can be done by software if you lack physical memory. Except detecting it and returning a 'clean' error